# Twitter ads API "GET /1/stats/accounts/:account_id" unauthorized access

Tags: twitter, postman

I am using postman APP for accessing GET request through TWITTER API. Though I am able to generate output through all other GET and POST request through OAUTH 1.0. But when I am sending the request through "GET /1/stats/accounts/:account_id" method, its generating the following error.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS",
      "message": "This request is not properly authenticated"
    }
  ],
  "request": {
    "params": {}
  }
}
```

I am using the following request :  "https://ads-api.twitter.com/1/stats/accounts/:18ce53yh9sw?entity_ids=88hjg&entity=CAMPAIGN&end_time=2017-05-14T17:00:00Z&granularity=HOUR&metric_groups=BILLING&placement=ALL_ON_TWITTER&start_time=2017-05-05T15:00:00Z"

This is the most important GET request for me to get the campaign level data. Any other way around may be helpful.

UPDATE:

The following request is working for https://ads-api.twitter.com/1/accounts/:account_id

```
{
  "request": {
    "params": {}
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Wadi.com",
      "business_name": null,
      "timezone": "Asia/Riyadh",
      "timezone_switch_at": "2013-05-21T21:00:00Z",
      "id": "18ce53yh9sw",
      "created_at": "2015-03-12T07:33:09Z",
      "salt": "0f034423fa35f95e8efc844a25c4d7a3",
      "updated_at": "2017-05-17T06:03:58Z",
      "business_id": null,
      "approval_status": "ACCEPTED",
      "deleted": false
    }
  ],
  "data_type": "account",
  "total_count": 1,
  "next_cursor": null
}
```

Regards
Shree Kant

Comment: Could you show us the GET request (along with authentication details) that is working properly as well?

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Is this issue resolved?